# Find difference between trunk and branch?

Tags: svn, diff

Is there a way to find the differences between the `trunk` and say a branch `0.4.x`?

I need to create a tag - however I can't remember if my latest corrections were done in the trunk or the branch.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

If you have a checkout of the repository at hand, you can use the `^` (caret, search for it in the [manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.basic.in-action.html)) notation to reference the root of the repo like this:

```
svn diff --old ^/branches/0.4.x --new ^/trunk
```

This works since Subversion 1.6.

If you have an older subversion or no handy checkout of the repo, you can use absolute paths, as described in the original [redbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re09.html):

```
svn diff --old http://.../repo/branches/0.4.x --new http://.../repo/trunk/
```

should give you the answer you're looking for.

Replace `http://.../repo/` with the actual URL of your repository.

Comment: This didn't work with the Mac OS X (Mountain Lion) included subversion (1.7).  I upgraded to subversion 1.8.1 with Homebrew and this worked.

Comment: With caret notation (SVN >= 1.6): svn diff --old ^/branches/0.4.x --new ^/trunk

Comment: @SteveKehlet: where `^` means "the repository of the checkout I'm currently in"?

Comment: @DavidSchmitt yes, the caret is shorthand for the root of the repo. [The manual has more info](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.basic.in-action.html), search for caret.

Answer (score 6):

```
svn diff ^/trunkUrl/fileName ^/branchUrl/fileName
```

This will give you the difference between a file in branch and trunk.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the meld tool for comparison instead of using command prompt to see the difference. It goes something like this.

```
svn diff --diff-cmd='meld' --old http://.../repo/branches/0.4.x --new http://.../repo/trunk/
```

Comment: What is the `meld` tool?

Comment: @ceving: I think he refers to [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/). In Ubuntu it should be already in the repository [Meld Diff Viewer](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lucid/meld/)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to diff against the current branch, you can just use a dot .

```
svn switch ^/branches/branchName
svn diff . ^/trunk
```