# svn diff branch and truck for a particular user

Tags: svn

I want to update the truck with the changes I checked into branch. But I want to update only the changes, I checked in not some other users. How do i do this.

found [Find difference between trunk and branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250873/find-difference-between-trunk-and-branch-svn) but that does not list changes for a particular user

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Search the output of `svn log` for just your revisions. Use TortoiseSVN's "show log" dialog and search for your username, or just do `svn log | grep your_user_name` to get the revision numbers you created.

Then merge just those revisions to trunk, using the `-r` or `-c` flags on `svn merge`.